# How to get data in proper JSON format

Tags: node.js, json, redis, nestjs

I am saving JSON object in redis as a string after stringifying it but when I am fetching it its
not showing in proper json format.Its showing like this below:

```
{
  "data": "{\"name\":\"digi\",\"age\":\"23\"}"
}
```

what I want is data in this format:

```
{
  data:{
        "name":"digi",
        "age":"23"  
      }
}
```

Below is my code:

```
async myLocation(){
     
    const profile = {
        "name":"digi",
        "age":"23"  
    }

    try{

        await this.cacheManager.set("Profile", JSON.stringify(profile), { ttl: 180 });
        var valu = await this.cacheManager.get("Profile");
       
        if(valu){
            
            return {data:valu}; 
        }
        else{
            return 'No key found';
        }
     }
     catch(err){
        console.log(err); 
        return err;
     }
 }
```

Someone let me know how can I get data in desired format.

Comment: `return { data: JSON.parse(value) }`

Comment: On doing `JSON.parse(valu)`.Ts showing this error `Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'`

Comment: just convert `valu`  to string before json parse `const data = JSON.parse(\`${valu || "{}"}\`)`

Comment: `var data = JSON.parse(value); retrun { data };` and handle the type with typescript if you want